# angular Foreach loop through the process and check condition

Tags: angularjs, foreach

```
$scope.users = [{
    user_id: 101,
    type: 2,
    name: "Harry"
  },
  {
    user_id: 102,
    type: 2,
    name: "James"
  }
];

$scope.item = {
  id: 10,
  type: 3
};

angular.forEach($scope.users, function(value, key) {
  if (value.type != $scope.item.type) {
    console.log('Sorry this is not for you!');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Let to confirm if it does not match with condition it should return console and exit

Try with break; keyword and return false does not work please guide

Comment: and what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Use Native `for` loop instead of angular `forEach`. It faster and allows you to break the loop as per condition. Sample below:

```
var test = function() {
    var users = [{
            user_id: 101,
            type: 2,
            name: "Harry"
        },
        {
            user_id: 102,
            type: 2,
            name: "James"
        }
    ];
    var item = {
        id: 10,
        type: 3
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (users[i].type != item.type) {
            console.log('breaking');
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
var keepGoing = true;
angular.forEach($scope.users, function(value, key) {

if (keepGoing) {
     if (value.type != $scope.item.type) {
console.log('Sorry this is not for you!');
keepGoing = false;
//return false;
    }
  }
});
```